# PHImageManager requestImageForAsset returns nil for iCloud photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

I try get photo with method requestImageForAsset.
Use options:

```
auto options = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES
```

Degraded image always correctly comes. But after this in info dictionary for key PHImageErrorKey:

> Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=25
>   "AbqGWakknY1m9XDzc0NwcDMDvxHE is unknown from the cloud"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=AbqGWakknY1m9XDzc0NwcDMDvxHE is
>   unknown from the cloud}

Answer (score 0):

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.synchronous = YES;
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
```